# Cannot get parameterized permalinks to SEDE queries I own

Tags: bug, data-explorer

When I create an SEDE query while logged in, and that query has parameters, there is no direct permalink to that query with certain parameter values, because the "permalink" button is "edit" in that case (and also the URL isn't updated).

**Steps to recreate (initially):**

1. Log in to SEDE.
2. Create a new query with a parameter, e.g. `SELECT ##Param##`.
3. Run the query, entering a parameter value.
4. Click *permalink* (you'll get a link with the values you just entered).
5. Change the parameter value and re-run.
6. Observe there is no way to generate a link with this new parameter value.

**Steps to recreate (existing query):**

1. Log in to SEDE.
2. Visit one of your queries as usual (e.g. the `/query/<id>` route).
3. Enter a parameter value and run the query.
4. Observe there is no way to generate a link with this new parameter value.

Here is an [animated GIF of this happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eSnR.gif).

This can be irritating when attempting to share the results of an existing parameterized query you've created where you've changed the parameter values.

Maybe it should always display a *permalink* button, even when *edit* is displayed, which links to the current parameter values.

**Workarounds**

From a comment (on an answer before I just merged it all into here), there is a relatively straightforward workaround:

> The easier work-around here is to just click "edit", fill in the parameters, run, and click "permalink" from the edit page. – Shog9♦

Also, before I knew about that, I made [a userscript](https://github.com/JC3/SEUserScripts/blob/master/SEDEPermalink.user.js) to add a *Get Link* button, which you can use *after* switching to the "permalink" version.